# Flexbox grid / tabs without wrapper

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a way to do the elements in this flexbox grid / tabs without putting them in a wrapper?

http://jsfiddle.net/mu98yotk/

```css
.test {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.test, .test .wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.test .wrapper {
    flex: 1;
}

.test .wrapper * {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the desired result...any child of a flex-container is a flex-item...so it's not clear what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.test {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
}
.test > * {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.test > p {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
</div>
```